# How to remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables
test
and test1

test

```
id formula 
1  A12+C32+D+X
2  K/Y
```

test1

```
   id Code 
    6  A12
    7  C32
   100 A1
    10 D
    12 X
    13 K
    14 Y
```

How can I update formula(text formlas) filed in the table test to get

```
id formula 
    1  [6]+[7]+[10]+[12]
    2  [13]/[14]
```

Itry the following script [sqlfield](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73ece/14) but it doesn't rerun the correct result . It returns

```
 RFORMULA
[6]+C32+D+X//need to remove it 
[13]/Y//need to remove it 
[13]/[14]//the best result 
[100]2+[7]+[10]+[12]
[13]/Y//need to remove it 
K/[14]//need to remove it 
[6]+[7]+[10]+[12]//the best result
```

I am working on it for hours , any idea ?

Comment: This question is tagged "mysql", but the SQL Fiddle is for SQL Server.  What database are you really using?

Comment: I swear I've seen this question twice already today...

Comment: This complex processing would be better done with application code, not SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by using the following:

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73ece/204)

```
WITH a AS
  ( SELECT DISTINCT A.id group_id,
    Split.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data
  FROM
    (SELECT id,
      CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(formula, '/', '/</M><M>'), '+','+</M><M>'), '-','+</M><M>'),'*','+</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
    FROM test
    ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
  ),
  b AS
  (SELECT group_id,
    REPLACE(LEFT(Data, LEN(Data)-1), t.[Code], concat(t.[id],RIGHT(Data,1))) yy,
    REPLACE(Data, t.[Code], t.[id])uu
  FROM a
  LEFT JOIN test1 t
  ON t.Code =LEFT(Data, LEN(Data)-1)
  OR (t.Code=Data)
  )


SELECT group_id,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(stuff(
  (SELECT uu FROM b WHERE newtable.group_id=group_id FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1,1,''), 'uu', ''), '</>', ''),'<', ''), '>', '')
FROM b newtable
GROUP BY group_id
```

Here, I have also specified multiplication and subtraction, in case they appear in your expression column. You can edit it accordingly if there exist some other ones:

```
CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(formula, '/', '/</M><M>'), '+','+</M><M>'), '-','+</M><M>'),'*','+</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
```